# Fetching data simultaneously in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I need to a clarification on this,I create a function with sharepreferrence which contain asyn, And in this same function am trying to fetch data from the server, And Am using FutureBuilder to display the output
 BUT what i observe is that the data keep fetching simultaneously,
What can it be the Problem. Here is the code

**My Function for fetching Data**

```
List<TransactionsModel> parseTransactons (String responseBody) {
  Map data = json.decode(responseBody);
  var output = data['transactions']; //returns a List of Maps
  final castingtoMAP =  output.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return castingtoMAP.map<TransactionsModel>((json) => 
    TransactionsModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<TransactionsModel>> fetchTransactions(http.Client client)  async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await 
  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String email = prefs.getString('Email');
  String session = prefs.getString('session');

  var map = new Map<String, String>();
  map["email"] = email;
  map["sesscode"] = session;

  var response = await http.post(new API().Transaction, body: map);
  print('*********Response from Transaction API***** $response');
  return parseTransactons(response.body); 
}
```

**Displaying Data**

```
FutureBuilder<List<TransactionsModel>>(
  future: fetchTransactions(http.Client()),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError)
       return MyFunctions().showToast(snapshot.error);
    return snapshot.hasData
      ? TransactionCardWidget(snapshot.data)
      : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
),
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "the data keep fetching simultaneously" ?

Comment: @Martyns The data keep fetching and fetching, i.e I use this to check  print('*********Response from Transaction API***** $response'); But This line keeps repeating itself and It makes the APp Freeze.

Comment: Are you using StatefulWidget or StatelessWidget?

Comment: @EsenMehmet. am using StateFulWidget.

Comment: @Harbdollar that's the problem. Execute the future inside initState with variable assign or use StatelessWidget.

Answer (score 3):

If your widget is `Stateless` or is `Stateful` and you are calling `setState` a new instance of `Future<List<TransactionsModel>>` is being created by calling `fetchTransactions`, thus making a new request. You need to save the `Future` that the function returns in the `State` of a `StatefulWidget` and then call `fetchTransactions` in the `initState` function.

```
class .... extends State<..> {
    Future<List<TransactionsModel>> transactionsFuture;

    void initState() {
        transactionsFuture = fetchTransactions(http.Client());
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        ...
        FutureBuilder<List<TransactionsModel>>(
            future: transactionsFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it means that, I must not use setState() when getting the data?

Comment: @Harbdollar In my example you are getting the data only once in the initState. After that, FutureBuilder will handler the rest, so you don´t need to call setState for the transactionModels. You can still call setState for other variables you could have in your State because the Future will not be recreated.

Comment: OK. But am just including the Futurebuilder in my ListView, though I didn't paste the whole code..

Comment: In this case it seems that your transactionsmodels can be fetched only once, so you can just make your ListView child of the FutureBuilder